# Objective-c Http connection - Autorelease no pool - just leaking

Tags: objective-c, http, memory, memory-leaks, autorelease

I have a http post connection method as shown below:

```
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:method];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"DataType" forHTTPHeaderField:dataType];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
response = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[request release];
result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseCode = [response statusCode];

[error release];
if(responseCode == 200) {
    [self connectionCompletedHere];
}
else 
{
    [self connectionFailedHere];
}
```

It works fine however im getting console messages like __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x62c3b80 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking.

using the leaks tool I have narrowed it down to 2 lines which are causing the leaks:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and

```
 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the code calling this method where is your autorelease pool?

Comment: The thing is i dont have an autorelease pool

Comment: Which is what the error says - you need to have one

Comment: I did add one but if the connection is dropped during the http post, the app crashes due to the fact the autorelease pool tries to release something that is not alloced anymore

Comment: That is another issue - NSURL URLWithString returns an autoreleased NSURL so you need the pool for that (and so much of Cocoa does this sort of thing you cannot do without the pool

Comment: Most likely there _is_ an autorelease pool, the one created in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not alloc/init/release NSError, it is a reference parameter, just declare it and pass it's address:

```
NSError *error;
```

reworked code:

```
...
response = nil;
NSError *error;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[request release];
result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseCode = [response statusCode];

if(responseCode == 200) {
...
```

Comment: Omg I could kiss you =D Thank you you have saved my life

Comment: You're welcome!  NSError is a strange "duck".  Up voting answers you think are good or useful to you helps others helps, I up-vote any answer that I read that seems good.

Comment: I was trying to upvote but apparently i need 15 reputation =/

Comment: Thanks! I remember getting started with SO, it wasn't easy getting the initial points so I could do anything.  For me not being able to add comments was something I wanted do to but couldn't.  I just up-voted your two questions, it seems the down-voting was a little harsh on your first question.